# partial applied function in the recursion

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am beginner in Haskell. I wrote a function, which applies another function several times to the argument:

```
frepeat :: (Integral n) => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
frepeat n f a
    | n <= 0 = error "Invalid count."
    | n == 1 = f a
    | otherwise = f (frepeat (n-1) f a)
```

It works:

```
ghci> frepeat 3 (^2) 2
256
ghci> frepeat 4 (++ "-bla") "bla"
"bla-bla-bla-bla-bla"
```

Now I want rewrite it *more compactly*, without the last argument. I want - it must to be a partial applied function. I tried this:

```
frepeat :: (Integral n) => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
frepeat n f
    | n <= 0 = error "Invalid count."
    | n == 1 = f
    | otherwise = f (frepeat (n-1) f)
```

But GHCi doesn't eat it... Does it mean I can't do it?

Comment: I would make the base case to be `n==0`, for which you can return `id`. Well, to be completely honest, at that point I wouldn't use recursion, but something like `foldr (.) id . replicate n`

Comment: @chi, I have not understood your answer. Can you show me the full code of your decission?

Comment: Thank you. It works:
`frepeat::Int->(a->a)->a->a
frepeat n f a
 | n == 0 = a
 | otherwise = foldr (\_ acc -> f acc) a (replicate n a)`

Comment: @chi, am I right: I can't to get rid from the `a` parameter this case, like I did it in my previous code version?

Comment: @chi, `fpow f n x = iterate f x !! n` is better, I think.

Comment: My full code was exactly `frepeat n = foldr (.) id . replicate n`. Here I removed both parameters `f,a`. You can go further and remove `n` as well, as in `frepeat = (foldr (.) id .) . replicate`, but I find this less readable. (This uses the fixed type `Int` for `n`, but this is a minor point). The alternative `iterate` solution is also very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need one extra (.) in the last part

```
| otherwise = f . (frepeat (n-1) f)
```

In general, this

```
let f x = f (g x)
```

can be rewritten as this

```
let f = f . g
```